# How to create a view with buttons and add them to a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uibutton

In my iOS app most of the GUI is made with the interface builder, but some parts are done programmatically.

One `UITableViewController` and its cells are done programmatically.
Now, I want to have a view with 3 buttons to a cell.

Usually, I would just make a custom cell with the interface builder and add it, but I want to use the view of the cell in another place where it must be a view and not a cell.

What's the best approach to make a view buttons (with the interface builder) and then add the view to a cell?

Since it's just a view, I don't know where to put the "gui logic" (*i.e. the events/event handling*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a static view used all over the app, then i would make a method in some utility class like `createGlobalButtonView` and it will do something like

```
UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIRoundedRectButton];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchButton1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[view addSubview button];
```

from there you can create 2 other buttons, and change the properties as you see fit. `frame` property being used to set the origin/dimensions `CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)` that will be the most used property. Remember to implement touchButton1:

```
- (void)touchButton1:(UIButton*)sender;
```

then when ever you need this view/buttons, you call the method to get one